# Making internal nexus repos available publicly

Tags: nexus, artifact

I would like to make some Nexus repos, that are available only from within our companies network, publicly available. To this I set up a host in a DMZ, and installed a Nexus instance there with proxy repos pointing to the internal Nexus repos. The problem is, that if someone checks the Nexus UI running in the DMZ, he is not seeing the actual content of the internal repos, as the artifacts appear only as per request in the proxy. I need some kind of a smart proxy like feature, but I am running the OSS Nexus release.
A suggestions I have found was to rsync over the appropriate folders to the externally available host. The problem is, that I only want to make specific repositories available, and as far as I see, the repo contents are not separated on filesystem level.
On the REST API I neither could find proper methods, so that I could periodically sync over the artifacts.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Nexus release: OSS 3.13.0-01

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a full answer so making a comment, but you can potentially restrict what is shared publically by making certain repositories not available to the other server by adjusting either anonymous or the user access used to access it.  You still wouldn't see everything though.  This is how NXRM3 works tho, if you proxy Central, you can't see everything in Central either.

Comment: Thanks joedragons for the comment. It might be useful at some point, but now I think I have found a solution with the help of the REST API. Still working on it...